# notificacion web

Tags: php, c#, asp.net, push-notification

Buenas quisiera consultarle aunque no es un problema si no una consulta si se podrá realizar notificación en web así como la aplicación whatsapp que cuando le hablan sale en la parte superior una notificación que quien te hablo , yo quisiera saber si cuando se hace una aplicacion web estes en la web y no se por ejemplo cuando se inserten salte una notificacion asi como la notificacion de whastapp .

siquiera saber si se puede hacer en cualquier lenguaje web php o asp.net c#

yo se que capas voten -1 o me lo cierran la pregunta

gracias a todos .

Comment: Lo que buscas lo puedes hacer, necesitas implementar **notificaciones 
 push** usando el api web de javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes implementar notificaciones push que son notificaciones automáticas a los navegadores web usando Notification API

**Puedes usar notificaciones push usando:**

- [NodeJs.](https://nickersoft.github.io/push.js/)
- [PHP](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php)
- [Rails](https://github.com/zaru/webpush)
- [Python](https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush)
- [Go Lang](https://github.com/appleboy/gorush)

> **Un pequeño tutorial aquí:** [Notificaciones Push Web](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/)

**Existen servicios que pueden ayudarte a implementar esto**

1. https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/ (Gratis)
2. https://onesignal.com/ (Gratis con soporte para movil)